# Why is General Relativity considered a gauge theory?

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory

Gauge theories are those which can be written with a Lie group as a symmetry group. 
According to Sean M Caroll's book, I can find the Lorentz group or Poincare group. So can General Relativity be a gauge theory?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346793/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/297697/50583